# Can I somehow use jupyter from remote server on Debian 9?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, remote-access

I want to use Jupyter on remote server runned by Debian 9. In local machine installed Windows 7. Is it possible to work on Jupyter via GUI from local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the Debian machine over the internet (or local network) you can use the IP address & port of the jupyter notebook to use the web IDE on any machine.

For instance, if you have an Amazon Web Services instance of Debian running, you'd go to the security group and add the jupyter notebook port to inbound and outbound rules.

Digital Ocean and other cloud providers don't have abstraction layers for security and will likely have active ports listening/broadcasting by default.

If it's in a LAN, such as your home network on a different machine or in a VM, open up a terminal in Debian and find your network IP by running `ifconfig` and looking at your main device information. This is most likely going to be `wlan0` or `eth0`, depending on ethernet or wireless access point method for connecting.

Then simply open your favorite browser on another computer, type that IP (without www) and the port like so `<ip address>:<port>`, and you should see your notebook.

Comment: Run notebook with `ipython notebook --debug` on the server you're attempting to connect to and share the output upon trying to visit the notebook remotely again

Comment: I connected, but kernel die everytime)